# Left join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables,

```
 itemmaster
|--------|----------|
|  id    |   name   |
|--------|----------|
|   1    |   Pizza  | 
|--------|----------|
|   2    |   Burger | 
|--------|----------|
|   3    |   Pepsi  | 
---------------------

     order
    |--------|----------|
    |orderid |   date   |
    |--------|----------|
    |   1    |   1-1-11 | 
    |--------|----------|
    |   2    |   2-1-11 | 
    |--------|----------|
    |   3    |   3-1-11 | 
    ---------------------


          orderdetails
        |--------|-------------|---------|---------|
        |  id    |   orderid   |itemid   |quantity |
        |--------|-------------|---------|---------|
        |   1    |   1         | 1       | 10      |
        |--------|-------------|---------|---------|
        |   2    |   1         | 2       | 20      |
        |--------|-------------|---------|---------|
        |   3    |   2         | 1       | 10      |
        -------------------------------------------
```

I want to join these 3 tables to get quantity of items of an order that placed on a particular date.
What I have tried is

```
$this->db->from('itemmaster');
$this->db->join('orderdetails', 'orderdetails.itemid= itemmaster.id','left');
$this->db->join('order', 'order.orderid= orderdetails.orderid');
$this->db->where('order.date',"1-1-11");            
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I got Result as,

```
Pizza------ 10
Burger------10
```

What I want is,

```
Pizza-------10
Burger------20
Pepsi-------0
```

Comment: try making your second join a left join too. In SQL directly, id try using coalesce (that replaces a null value by something). For example coalesce(numberofBurger,0). If the numberofBurger is null, youd see a 0 in your query result

Comment: @Alex : Thanks for your help. I have tried making second join left, but still i am getting only 1 item.

Comment: if we go step by step and do one join at a time, do you always get only 1 result?

Comment: If there is only one join (first one) and there is no where statement, I am getting multiple items as expected.

Comment: And only the second left join will return only 1 result i guess? that's kinda odd. I don't have any way of testing this on my computer atm. :/ And is there a mistake in your querry or your table declaration? because it is written itemmaster.itemid while the table only has a column name id

Comment: That's actually a typo in my question. I have changed it. I thank that "where" statement cause issue.Without "where", left join works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62616/discussion-between-alex-and-basim-sherif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the all the joins to left joins, you can always do it in two separate query and do a union between the two of them. One would get all the lines that actualy have a quantity and the other would get the rests and put them toguether.

It would look a bit like this. there might be some synthax error, but you'll have to rewrite it in php anyway:

p.s. to add up the quantities, you can use sum()

```
Select itemmaster.name, orderdetails.quantity from itemmaster 
left join orderdetails on orderdetails.itemid = itemmaster.id 
left join order on order.orderid = orderdetails.orderid 
where order.date = '1-1-11'
group by itemmaster.name

Union 
Select itemmaster.name, '0' as quantity From itemmaster 
except (Select itemmaster.name, orderdetails.quantity from itemmaster 
left join orderdetails on orderdetails.itemid = itemmaster.id 
left join order on order.orderid = orderdetails.orderid 
where order.date = '1-1-11'
group by itemmaster.name)
group by itemmaster.name
```

hope this helps ! good luck